# Bootstrap-Datetimepicker Not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have been looking at this for 2 days, and cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is a fiddle with my project. http://jsfiddle.net/dagger2002/RR4hw/

Here is the HTML

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:75px;">
        <div class='col-md-5'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>Start</div>

                <div class='input-group date' id='startDate'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="startDate" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-5'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>End</div>

                <div class='input-group date' id='endDate'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="org_endDate" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery.

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#startDate').datetimepicker();
    jQuery('#endDate').datetimepicker();
    jQuery("#startDate").on("dp.change",function (e) {
        jQuery('#endDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(e.date);
    });
    jQuery("#endDate").on("dp.change",function (e) {
        jQuery('#startDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMaxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

I am getting no errors and when I run it through fiddle it says no errors found. I am new to jQuery so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Oh yeah. I am using long name do to this going into a joomla site that is also using moo tools.

Thanks in Advance.

UPDATE

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en-gb">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <title>DateTime Test</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />


        <!-- Style Sheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.0/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.0.0/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/lang/en-gb.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery.noConflict();
        // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:75px;">
               <div class='col-md-5'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div>Start</div>

                        <div class='input-group date' id='startDate'>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" name="startDate" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-5'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div>End</div>

                        <div class='input-group date' id='endDate'>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" name="org_endDate" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This jFiddle works. http://jsfiddle.net/RR4hw/11/

But when I incorporate it into a regular page it breaks. Not sure what I am messing up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seemed to be some issues with the external resources in your jsFiddle.

I have updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RR4hw/7/) to work.  I changed the external resources and made some minor adjustments to the code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:75px;">
       <div class='col-md-5'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>Start</div>

                <div class='input-group date' id='startDate'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="startDate" />
                    <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-5'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>End</div>

                <div class='input-group date' id='endDate'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="org_endDate" />
                    <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#startDate').datetimepicker({ format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss' });
    jQuery('#endDate').datetimepicker({ format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss' });
    jQuery("#startDate").on("dp.change",function (e) {
        jQuery('#endDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(e.date);
    });
    jQuery("#endDate").on("dp.change",function (e) {
        jQuery('#startDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMaxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

- In your jsFiddle, you reference "bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" and not "bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js".
- it seems that "bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" needs "moment.js" as a prerequisite.  Please note that the order of includes matter.
- Finally, "en-gb.js" needs to be listed after "bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js".

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RR4hw/11/) with working solution.

Comment: What did you change? on the externals. I see you added the format into the jQuery. Is that all?

Comment: I used different URLs from what you had.  same filenames but different urls.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just realized that you changed it from bootstrap 3.1 to bootstrap 2.2. That wont work as my site is using bootstrap 3. The time script version I was using works with bootstrap 3.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Outside of jFiddle. I will update Code above.

Comment: I guess I should add the date time script to the bottom. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks malkassem! I didn't know the order of js scripts in jsfiddle matters. Just like in real development I guess.

Answer (score 6):

Script include order in jsFiddle is not working, below is the modified order for workable sample. As suggested by @malkassem moment.js is required for bootstrap date picker to work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>        
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/lang/en-gb.js"></script>                
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.0.0/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get date and/or time picker working is by installing below package

```
Install-Package Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS
```

and then reference installed files in _Layout

```
<!-- JS -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   <!-- Bootstrap v3.3.5 -->
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Core.js"></script>
```

and then add below script to layout page before `</body>` tag

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('.datepicker').datetimepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' });
    jQuery('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();

});
</script>
```

in Razor view use as below

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyDateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using ASP MVC's default _Layout.cs file, Remove these script imports at bottom or put it on the top.

```
Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set date according to your fomate.

Front end side

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
   selectMonths: true,
   selectYears: true,
   format: 'd/m/yyyy'
});
```

Back end side

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime($student->dob));
```