# DatePicker doesn't have any Bootstrap styling

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using the below code to use DatePicker

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      eventSources: [
        {
          url: 'data.php',
          type: 'POST'
        }
      ]
    })
  });
</script>
```

but it doesn't seem to look right.

Is this right or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. I found a question asked in April this year, about this datepicker:
[Bootstrap-Datetimepicker Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846525/bootstrap-datetimepicker-not-working)

The accepted answer to that question references a JSFiddle, upon inspecting that link, I conclude that the Datepicker is supposed to look like that.